# "Moving" applications between speakers on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, volume-mixer

I have a number of speakers on my Windows 10 laptop: the laptop speakers, the monitor speakers and a Bluetooth sound bar. How could I set which application sound is output where? Even just a default would be useful -- for example, the BT speakers are picked up from the next room, it'd be nice if I could just make everything use the laptop speakers for a while.

Comment: You can select as default any output device. All apps should use unless told otherwise, if that option is available (e.g. VLC). Some apps but not all allow selecting a different output device overriding the OS settings.

Comment: How can you select.

Comment: System settings or right-click in the "speaker" icon/indicator.

Comment: Ah right click and then "playback devices". Gotcha. Windows 10 has Control Panel and PC Settings confusing me greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [EarTrumpet](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/eartrumpet/9nblggh516xp?SilentAuth=1&wa=wsignin1.0&activetab=pivot:overviewtab) is a great solution to all these problems. Once set to an output device it will play on that if it becomes available.